# Ubuntu 19.10 is frozen, but not frozen?

Tags: nvidia

So i have 2 Hp Laptops both the same but one is a downgrade pavilion where mine is the top one. they are both about 6-7 years old so not new but they work. My laptop is a HP Pavlion, I7 with 8GB of ram running and a Nividia Geforce with Ubuntu 19.10 where as the other one is a HP Pavlion, duel core with 4GB of ram running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

The reason i mention this is they both have the same issue so i dont think this has anything to do with what version of Ubuntu i have but what is happening is the screen will freeze, you can see everything in the background moving but you just cant click on anything. At first i can do Ctrl + Alt + T and get the terminal up and write but i just cant click anywhere else without restarting my laptop. Im starting to think a hardware issue.

Has anyone else come across this issue before?

Comment: Before the freeze, does everything work normally as expected? If you start terminal, can you type normal CLI commands and get proper responses? Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: Yeah it does, i did your command and i get ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
ls: cannot access '/home/simon/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory

Comment: I'd check for current video drivers on both machines, and also check the BIOS version and make sure it's up to date. Use `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to support.hp.com and check for a newer one.

Comment: What do you see at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/?

Comment: the bios version is all up to date. and extensions.gnome.org/local nothing is there :(

Comment: What about video drivers?

Comment: They all seem to be updated too, although I think it is a Ram issue. Thunderbird was downloading my emails just over 100k of them and I've noticed as soon as I boot it up after a while it slows down and stops. I've now I've limited it to 30days it seems to be fine so I'm thinking it's having a issue with my ram

Comment: Show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` on both machines.

Comment: total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.8Gi       2.1Gi       3.8Gi       163Mi       1.8Gi       5.2Gi
Swap:         1.7Gi          0B       1.7Gi

Comment: vm.swappiness = 60

Comment: i cant get to the other machine at the moe also ive found when the laptop sleeps it loads back with a noise screen

Comment: its showing i have NVA5 when i have NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 230M] so there may be some logic to this card issue

Comment: Your Nvidia should be version 340.1080. `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii`

Comment: Thats not showing anything :S

Comment: Based on the video card that you called out, you don't appear to have any Nvidia drivers installed. Go to https://www.geforce.com/drivers and download 340.1080 and install it. Do both machines have the same Nvidia?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: In the end I tried, Zorion OS, elementary OS, Linux mint and every one of them did the same so I'm thinking maybe it's something to do with Debian, I'm now installing Manjaro so Arch Linux, it does suck as I needed Ubuntu as my server is Ubuntu and it would have been nice to learn the same commands but once ive given Manjaro a go I'll give you a update :)

Comment: It must be a hardware issue that requires a special kernel parameter in GRUB.

Comment: So I tried Manjaro and got exactly the same issue 

Comment: Just to summarize, you've checked the BIOS version, and installed the Nvidia drivers, yes? Did you run `memtest`?

Comment: Yep done all of that, bios is up to date, graphics is 08 it won't take the 10 and yes I did run memtest all is good

Comment: Thanks for the update. I don't have any more ideas for you to follow.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and thanks for trying, I'm going to do another memtest. The strange thing is I was using Ubuntu on this laptop 3-4 years ago

Comment: The big difference is the newer kernel, and maybe that's the trouble that you're having. Try booting to a 18.xx Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if it works.

Comment: I'll have alook and try although I really like the plasma option :)

Comment: Well then use the Kubuntu Live 18.xx version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end there does not seem to be any fix, my only solution was to download Kubuntu and from time to time it will freeze but shutting the lid down and causing it to sleep seems tos solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I get that sometimes on my Ubuntu 18.04.3. Last time when I checked the system logs it seemed that it's all caused by a lack of free memory (I have 8GB RAM).

I found a workaround so I don't have to restart my computer and it's simply restarting gnome with: `Alt+F2` typing `r` and pressing `Enter`.

And if that is not working you could try to open your terminal and restart gnome from there with: `killall -3 gnome-shell`

Comment: You probably have a bad GNOME Shell extension installed.

Comment: Glad its not just me then :D ill give your ideas a go when it next freezes :) although Alt+F2 does not work on mine when it freezes.